# InputField usage

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a controller I need look-up field in VF page I am using in below format but I am not getting.Could you please help me.

```
<apex:Page controller="DemoController">
 <apex:form>
<apex:pageBlock>
<apex:inputfield value="{!bc.Teacher__c}"/>
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
 public class DemoController{
 public student__c bc{get;set;}

 public DemoController();

  bc = new student__c();

}
```

Comment: Did it allowed to save your page? The reason am asking you is apex:inputField can only be allowed with apex:form tags.

Comment: Hi Vigneshwaran form tag is there but i missed while posting.How can i get look-up field value in vf page

Comment: Only problem i could think of is the permissions. Check whether your profile have the edit access to the lookup field.

Comment: When i use above code means i am getting text field rather than inputfield

Comment: In profile level EIDT permission is there.

Comment: If you get a text field, that means Teacher__c is type of text and not lookup. If you have a lookup field then it will come as Lookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a lookup field then it will come as Lookup.

```
<apex:page Controller="OpportunityExt">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:inputfield value="{!opp.Contact_lookup__c}"/>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

```
public class OpportunityExt {

    public String getOpportunity() {
        return null;
    }
    public Opportunity opp{get;set;}
    public OpportunityExt(){
        opp = new Opportunity();
    }
}
```

**Contact_lookup__c** is a lookup Field on Opportunity.

[image]

Comment: SfdcBat in my case both are custom objects only when i tried as per your suggestions still not working.Can you please change your code to both custom objects and modify here plz

Comment: It does not matter if it is custom or standard object. It works for both. Idea of `<apex:inputefield>` is to show the field based on the type- `text,picklist,date,lookup` etc. Pls add screenshot of your VF page(like mine) and data model(showing `student__c` object has a lookup field named `teacher__c`).